# SUMO and OpenDS Integration using TraCI

Tags: sumo

I am looking at having SUMO as the mobility server and I would like to map an OpenDS vehicle object onto the SUMO simulation by interfacing with SUMO using TraCI. A human user would be interacting with OpenDS through a driving machine and the aim is to create a human-in-the-loop simulation. I would be looking at transmitting mobility information in a bidirectional manner between SUMO and OpenDS.

I am relatively new to this area and I was not able to find suitable references. I would appreciate pointers to any relevant documentation or projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several projects coupling SUMO to driving simulators, the PARCOURS project has been described [here](http://sumo.dlr.de/2016), the rFPro solution [here](http://sumo.dlr.de/2017) (also look at the proceedings), but unfortunately I do not know of any available open source implementation. Usually the couple using the TraCI interface with the most important command being [vehicle.moveToXY](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/daily/pydoc/traci._vehicle.html#VehicleDomain-moveToXY) which synchronizes the position of the user-driven vehicle with its counterpart in SUMO.

Comment: Thank you Michael. The requirement is for OpenDS and the complexity is in synchronizing the vehicle movements. Right now, OpenDS only seems to allow controlling traffic light intersections from SUMO. It should be possible to control the vehicle object from OpenDS by using TraCI commands related to vehicle state but I am yet to try it out and have not seen any similar attempts made till now. Thank you for the reference projects.

Comment: Please consider contributing the result back to the community and adding a link to the repo here.